# Error connection refused localhost:5000/user from another device

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make a collaborative whiteboard, where multiple clients connect to the server and each can see what everyone is drawing on the board. The way that it is run is first you have to type in the terminal `node server.js` to execute the server.js file, which runs on localhost:5000. After that you open a new terminal and then type `npm start` and it opens the React app on localhost:3000.
Now the problem is that my other device tells me `GET http://localhost:5000/user net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I click on inspect. This is the link to show me JSON data of pictures from the MySQL database. So I cannot see pictures from the database on the whiteboard on different devices. Only on my own device. But the weird thing is that I can only see the JSON data when I explicitly type the IP address and then the port and `/user` in a different tab. But on the whiteboard itself, it tells me this error and shows me no pictures from the database.

This is the server.js code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const mysql = require('mysql')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      port: "3306",
      user: "root",
      password: "----",
      database: "pictures"
})


connection.connect(function(error){
      if(error) console.log(error);
      else console.log("connected");
});

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      connection.query('select * from pictures', function(error, rows, fields){
            if(error) console.log(error);
    
            else{
                console.log(rows);
                res.send(rows);
    
            }
    
      });
    });

io.on('connection', (socket)=> {
      console.log('User Online');

      socket.on('canvas-data', (data)=> {
            socket.broadcast.emit('canvas-data', data);
            
      })
})

var server_port = process.env.YOUR_PORT || process.env.PORT || 5000;
http.listen(server_port, () => {
    console.log("Started on : "+ server_port);
})
```

And this is the react component for my whiteboard:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Board from '../board/Board';
import DragMove from "../DragMove";
import $ from 'jquery';
import Safe from "react-safe";
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Text, View,FlatList} from 'react-native';
import './style.css';


class Container extends React.Component
{
  
    state ={
        userData:[],
        images:[{image:'images/kitten.jpg'}, {image:'images/penguin.jpg'}],
        id: 0
      }
    
      timeout;
      socket = io.connect();
  
      ctx;
      isDrawing = false;
      rect = true;
      image;

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.socket.on("canvas-data", function(data){

            var root = this;
            var interval = setInterval(function(){
                if(root.isDrawing) return;
                root.isDrawing = true;
                clearInterval(interval);
                var image = new Image()
                var canvas = document.querySelector('#board');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                image.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                    
                    root.isDrawing = false;
                };
                image.src = data;
            }, 200)
        })
        
    }
 
    
        async componentDidMount() {
            this.drawOnCanvas();
            const url = "http://localhost:5000/user";
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json(); 
            this.setState({userData: data});
            console.log(this.state.userData);
            var root = this;
            var canvas=document.getElementById("board");
            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
            var $canvas=$("#board");
            var Offset=$canvas.offset();
            var offsetX=Offset.left;
            var offsetY=Offset.top;
    
            var x,y,width,height;
    
            var $images=$(".img");
    
            $(function(){
                $images.draggable({
                    helper:'clone',
                });
    
            $images.each(function(index, element){
                $(this).data("imagesIndex", index);
            });
    
            $canvas.droppable({
                drop:dragDrop,
            });
    
            function dragDrop(e, ui){
                x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX)-1;
                y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY-125);
                width=ui.helper[0].width;
                height=ui.helper[0].height;
    
                var image = new Image();
                var theIndex=ui.draggable.data("imagesIndex");
                ctx.drawImage($images[theIndex], x, y, width, height);
    
                var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
                var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
                tempCanvas.width=width;
                tempCanvas.height=height;
                //tempCtx.drawImage(canvas,x,y,width,height,0,0,width,height);
                var img=new Image();

                img.onload=function(){
                    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height )
                };
                img.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
                console.log(img.src);
               
                $(".img").dblclick(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                    });     
            }
    
            })
    }

    changeColor(params) {
        this.setState({
            color: params.target.value
        })
    }

    changeSize(params) {
        this.setState({
            size: params.target.value
        })
    }
    




    clickMe(){
        this.rect = true
        alert(this.rect)
    }
 

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = newProps.color;
        this.ctx.lineWidth = newProps.size;
    }

    drawOnCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#board');
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var ctx = this.ctx;

        var sketch = document.querySelector('#dropHere');
        var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
        canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
        canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

        var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
        var last_mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

        /* Mouse Capturing Work */
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
            last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

            mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        }, false);


        /* Drawing on Paint App */
        ctx.lineWidth = this.props.size;
        ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.props.color;

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false);

        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false);

        var root = this;
        var onPaint = function() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
            ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();

            if(root.timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(root.timeout);
            root.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                var base64ImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                root.socket.emit("canvas-data", base64ImageData);
            }, 1000)
        };
    }

    render() {
    
        return (
            
            <div className="container">
            <div className="tools-section">
                <div className="color-picker-container">
                    Select Brush Color : &nbsp; 
                    <input type="color" value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
                </div>

                <div className="brushsize-container">
                    Select Brush Size : &nbsp; 
                    <select value={this.state.size} onChange={this.changeSize.bind(this)}>
                        <option> 5 </option>
                        <option> 10 </option>
                        <option> 15 </option>
                        <option> 20 </option>
                        <option> 25 </option>
                        <option> 30 </option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
    
            <div className="board-container">
                
                
            
                <h4>Select picture!</h4>
            
                    
                        {this.state.userData.map(image => (
                            <div className="dragImg"><img id={"gif"+this.state.id++} className="img" src={image.picture} width='200px' height='100px'/></div>
                            
                        ))}
            
                            
                <div id="dropHere"><canvas className="board" id="board" color={this.state.color} size={this.state.size}></canvas></div>
                
                <button onClick={()=>this.clickMe()}>Click me</button>                            

        
            </div>
        </div>

                    
           
        );
    }

    
}



export default Container
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can able to get/see the image from the other device with the IP, then probably it is not a problem of your application.

**Device-A** (server with node, react, database)
Here you have the application deployed. `http://localhost:xxxx` will work here in this device. I could see you have hardcoded `localhost` in the code. Try to make it as IP address of Device-A (whereever you have hard-codeded, change it to IP, like `192.168.x.x`)

**Device-B** (client - from which you are trying to access the server Device-A)
Here, you should provide the IP address (`192.168.x.x`) of Device-A while testing.

**Note:**

- I suggest `192.168.x.x` like IP address than using `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` even in the same machine to avoid confusion while testing with multiple devices.
- Use `http://192.168.x.x` in the browser as well (in the same machine)

Comment: Hey @dvidvid, as you were ready to share the code, I suggest to push your changes to github and publish. It must be a useful one in this work from home situation!

Comment: yes i will later on when my project finishes thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably binding to 127.0.0.1 which will make your service available to your localhost only. Try binding to 0.0.0.0.

Specifically here:

```js
http.listen(server_port, '0.0.0.0', () => {...});
```